# What if correlation coefficient is much less whereas the p-values is much lesser than the our significance level?

Tags: statistics, correlation, python, p-value

I have a data between rating of the restaurant and the approximate price of food in the restaurant. After doing Hypothesis testing. The pearson correlation coefficient was found to be 0.33 whereas p value was calculated much lesser than .05. Which means we have to accept our Alternate hypothesis as the finding is statistically significant. Our Alternate Hypothesis was that there is some relation between the two variables. Which is contrary to what we got as the coefficient i.e 0.33 which says there is no relation between the two. Why this trade off. Can anyone tell me whether I am going wrong or am I missing something regarding the concepts.

Here is what I have tried.

You can download the data [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MLbOXTsyDZ00im3cv98X07Rk8vgNha9_/view?usp=sharing)

```
from scipy import stats 
import pandas as pd
pear = pd.read_csv("stop.csv")
pearson_coef, p_value = stats.pearsonr(pear['approx_cost(for two people)'], pear['rate']) 
print("Pearson Correlation Coefficient: ", pearson_coef, "and a P-value of:", p_value) # Results
```

Output :

```
Pearson Correlation Coefficient:  0.32609607011051456 and a P-value of: 3.595009214519809e-228
```

According to my understanding both p value and coefficient should be related.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what correlation coefficients mean. They range from $-1$ to $1$, with $0$ indicating no correlation (which is not the same as independent). A value of $0.326$ may be closer to $0$ than to $1$ (arithmetically, not geometrically!), but it's not "too small to count". The $p$-value shows your result is significant.

Comment: But why is the p value so so so small. I mean aren't they both related. The p value is of the order of -228. Don't you think there is something wrong?

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar No, because you're comparing variables with different purposes: one says how strongly variables are correlated, the other how little chance there is it would seem that way if they weren't. For example, if the coefficient were Normally distributed with a very small standard deviation, even a modest nonzero value would be statistically significant. (Its actual distribution is [more esoteric than that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Using_the_exact_distribution), but the principle's much the same.) I bet you have a reasonably large dataset.

Comment: Oh got it thank you so much. Yes I have a dataset with around 12000 data

Answer (score 1):

A correlation coefficient of 0.33 does not indicate no correlation, rather just a weak one.  For there to be no correlation, a correlation coefficient of much nearer 0 (such as 0.01) would be required. Given $R = 0.326$, $R^2 = 0.106$. In other words, 10.6% of the variance between restaurant's ratings can be explained by the prices of their food. Assuming that your measurement of approximate price is reflective of what people consider, you should start thinking about what other factors could influence reviews.